# Is AMD's RX 5700 suitable for Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have the following setup:

[image]

On the scene I'm able to select GPU Compute as device:

[image]

But the issues start when I start the rendering, it seems to be building a new kernel and having this as the last text on screen:

[image]

And after that Blender is crashing.

Object does not need to be hard, basic starting box is just enough.

Blender version is 2.83.4 on Windows 10.

"Compiling render kernels"

Comment: ... why do you have a problem with that? It does what it needs to before rendering so what?

Comment: I'm sorry @MartynasŽiemys, my question was incomplete. The problem is that Blender is crashing with that setup.

Comment: The AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT appears to work properly with the Adrenalin 2020 Edition 20.11.2 Optional (WHQL).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, AMD GPUs take some minutes the first time you gonna render something. Indeed it has to compile kernel every time you open a new instance of blender.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be case @eduklafke, but in my case Blender never ends that, but crashing without any warning.